# PHP jQuery File Upload permission

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

The following script is PHPRUNNER 7.1 upload handler.

I want to set file permission/CHMOD after upload, from 0644 (cpanel default) to 0777.

For example `chmod($file, 0777);`, but i have no idea where to put the code:

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 5.11.1
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

class UploadHandler
{
    public $formStamp;
    public $pageType;
    public $table;
    public $field;
    public $tkeys;
    public $options;

    /**
     * Project settings 
     * @var {object}
     */
    public $pSet = null;

    function UploadHandler($options=null) {
        $this->formStamp = "";
        $this->pageType = "";
        $this->table = "";
        $this->field = "";
        $this->tkeys = "";  

        $this->options = array();
        $this->options['script_url'] = GetTableLink('mfhandler');
        $this->options['param_name'] =  'files';
        // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
        // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
        $this->options['delete_type'] =  'DELETE';
        $this->options['max_totalFile_size'] =  null;
        // The php.ini settings upload_max_filesize and post_max_size
        // take precedence over the following max_file_size setting:
        $this->options['max_file_size'] =  null;
        $this->options['min_file_size'] =  0;
        $this->options['resizeOnUpload'] =  false;

        $this->options['accept_file_types'] =  '/.+$/i';

        // The maximum number of files for the upload directory:
        $this->options['max_number_of_files'] =  null;
        // Image resolution restrictions:
        $this->options['max_width'] =  null;
        $this->options['max_height'] =  null;
        $this->options['min_width'] =  1;
        $this->options['min_height'] =  1;
        // Set to true to rotate images based on EXIF meta data, if available:
        $this->options['image_versions'] =  array();
        if ($options)
        {
            foreach($options as $key=>$value)
            {
                if(array_key_exists($key, $this->options))
                {
                    $this->options[$key] = $options[$key];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function getFullUrl() {
        $https = strlen($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 0 && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off';
        return
            ($https ? 'https://' : 'http://').
            (strlen($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) != 0 ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].'@' : '').
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].
            ($https && $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 443 ||
            $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 80 ? '' : ':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']))).
            substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/'));
    }

    public function set_file_delete_url($file) {
        $file["delete_url"] = $this->options['script_url']
            .'?file='.rawurlencode($file["name"]);
        $file["delete_type"] = $this->options['delete_type'];
        if ($file["delete_type"] !== 'DELETE') {
            $file["delete_url"] .= '&_method=DELETE';
        }
    }

    public function get_file_object($file_name) {
        $file_path = $this->pSet->getUploadFolder($this->field).$file_name;
        if (is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.') {
            $file = array();
            $file["error"] = false;
            $file["name"] = $file_path;
            $file["usrName"] = $file_name;
            $path_parts = $this->pathinfo_local($file_name);
            $file["type"] = getContentTypeByExtension($path_parts["extension"]);
            $file["size"] = filesize($file_path);
            $file["url"] = rawurlencode($file_path);
            $file["thumbnail"] = "";
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if ($file_path)
                {
                    $thumbPath = $this->pSet->getUploadFolder($this->field).$this->pSet->getStrThumbnail($this->field).$file_name;
                    if(is_file(getabspath($thumbPath)))
                    {
                        $file["thumbnail"] = $thumbPath;
                        $path_parts = $this->pathinfo_local($thumbPath);
                        $file["thumbnail_type"] = getContentTypeByExtension($path_parts["extension"]);
                        $file["thumbnail_size"] = filesize(getabspath($thumbPath));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $file["thumbnail"] = $file_path;
                        $file["thumbnail_type"] = $file["type"];
                        $file["thumbnail_size"] = $file["size"];
                    }
                }               
            }
            $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
            return $file;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function validate($uploadedFile, &$file, $error, $file_size, $index, $uploadDir) {
        if ($error) {
            $file["error"] = $error;
            return false;
        }
        if (!$file["name"]) {
            $file["error"] = "File name was not provided";
            return false;
        }
        if (!preg_match($this->options['accept_file_types'], $file["name"])) {
            $file["error"] = "File type is not acceptable";
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->options['max_file_size'] && (
                $file_size > $this->options['max_file_size'] * 1024 ||
                $file["size"] > $this->options['max_file_size'] * 1024)
            ) {
            $file["error"] = mysprintf("File size exceeds limit of %s kbytes", array($this->options['max_file_size']));
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->options['min_file_size'] &&
            $file_size < $this->options['min_file_size'] * 1024) {
            $file["error"] = mysprintf("File size must not be less than %s kbytes", array($this->options['min_file_size']));
            return false;
        }
        if (is_int($this->options['max_totalFile_size']) && (
                $this->getUploadFilesSize() + $file["size"] > $this->options['max_totalFile_size'] * 1024)
            ) {
            $file["error"] = mysprintf("Total files size exceeds limit of %s kbytes", array($this->options['max_totalFile_size']));
            return false;
        }
        if (is_int($this->options['max_number_of_files']) && (
                $this->getUploadFilesCount() >= $this->options['max_number_of_files'] && $this->options['max_number_of_files'] > 0)
            ) {
                if($this->options['max_number_of_files'] > 1)
                    $file["error"] = mysprintf("You can upload no more than %s files", array($this->options['max_number_of_files']));
                else 
                    $file["error"] = "You can upload only one file";
            return false;
        }
        if(isImageType($uploadedFile["type"]))
        {
            $image_size = runner_getimagesize($uploadedFile["tmp_name"], $uploadedFile);

            $img_width = $image_size[0];
            $img_height = $image_size[1];       
            if (is_int($img_width)) {
                if (($this->options['max_width'] && $img_width > $this->options['max_width'] ||
                        $this->options['max_height'] && $img_height > $this->options['max_height']) 
                        && !$this->options['resizeOnUpload']) {
                    $file["error"] = 'maxResolution';
                    return false;
                }
                if ($this->options['min_width'] && $img_width < $this->options['min_width'] ||
                        $this->options['min_height'] && $img_height < $this->options['min_height']) {
                    $file["error"] = 'minResolution';
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function getUploadFilesCount(){
        $result = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp] as $fileArray)
            if(!$fileArray["deleted"] && count($fileArray)>0)
                $result++;
        return $result;
    }

    public function getUploadFilesSize(){
        $result = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp] as $fileArray)
            if(!$fileArray["deleted"])
                $result += $fileArray["file"]["size"];
        return $result;
    }

    public function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
        // Handle form data, e.g. $_REQUEST['description'][$index]
    }

    public function handle_file_upload($uploadedFile, $index) {
        $tmpName = $uploadedFile["tmp_name"];
        $name = $uploadedFile["name"];
        $size = $uploadedFile["size"];
        $type = $uploadedFile["type"];
        $error = $uploadedFile["error"];
        $fileInfo = array("name" => $name, "size" => intval($size), "type" => $type, "isThumbnail" => false);
        $uploadDir = $this->pSet->getFinalUploadFolder($this->field, $fileInfo);
        $uploadDirRelative = $this->pSet->getUploadFolder($this->field, $fileInfo);
        $file = array();
        $file["error"] = false;
        $file["name"] = trim_file_name($name, $type, $index, $this);
        $file["usrName"] = $file["name"];
        $file["size"] = intval($size);
        switch($type)
        {
            case "image/png":
            case "image/x-png":
                $file["type"] = "image/png";
                break;
            case "image/jpeg":
            case "image/pjpeg":
                $file["type"] = "image/jpeg";
                break;
            default:
                $file["type"] = $type;
        }
        $path_parts = $this->pathinfo_local($name);
        if($file["type"] == "")
            $file["type"] = getContentTypeByExtension($path_parts["extension"]);
        $file["isImg"] = false;
        $file["thumbnail"] = "";
        if($this->pSet->isMakeDirectoryNeeded($this->field))
        {
            if(!makeSurePathExists($uploadDir))
            {
                $file["error"] = "Upload folder doesn't exist";
                return $file;
            }
        }
        else if(!is_dir($uploadDir))
        {
            $file["error"] = "Upload folder doesn't exist";
            return $file;
        }
        if ($this->validate($uploadedFile, $file, $error, $size, $index, $uploadDir)) {
            $file["isImg"] = CheckImageExtension($tmpName) != false;
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $file["name"] = $this->tempnam_sfx($uploadDir, $path_parts["filename"], $path_parts["extension"]);
            $file_path = $uploadDir.$file["name"];
            clearstatcache();
            upload_File($uploadedFile, $file_path);
            $file_size = filesize($file_path);
            if($this->options["resizeOnUpload"]){
                $tempOptions = array( 
                    'max_width' => $this->options["max_width"], 
                    'max_height' => $this->options["max_width"]);
                $new_file_name = $this->tempnam_sfx($uploadDir, $path_parts["filename"],$path_parts["extension"]);
                if($this->create_scaled_image($uploadDir.$file["name"], $uploadDir, $new_file_name, $tempOptions, $file, false, $uploadDirRelative, $uploadedFile)){
                    unlink($file_path);
                    $file["name"] = $new_file_name;
                    $file_path = $uploadDir.$new_file_name;
                    $file_size = filesize($file_path);
                }
            }
            if ($file_size === $file["size"]) {
                $file["url"] = $uploadDir.rawurlencode($file["name"]);
                foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                    $fileInfoThimbnail = array("name" => $name, "size" => intval($size), "type" => $type, "isThumbnail" => true);
                    $thumbUploadDir = $this->pSet->getFinalUploadFolder($this->field, $fileInfoThimbnail);
                    $thumbUploadDirRelative = $this->pSet->getUploadFolder($this->field, $fileInfoThimbnail);
                    if($this->pSet->isMakeDirectoryNeeded($this->field))
                    {
                        if(!makeSurePathExists($thumbUploadDir))
                            continue;
                    }
                    $thumbnail_name = $this->tempnam_sfx($thumbUploadDir, 
                        $options['thumbnailPrefix'].$path_parts["filename"], $path_parts["extension"]);
                    if ($this->create_scaled_image($uploadDir.$file["name"], $thumbUploadDir, $thumbnail_name, $options, $file
                            , true, $thumbUploadDirRelative, $uploadedFile)) {
                        clearstatcache();
                        $file_size = filesize($file_path);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                unlink($file_path);
                $file["error"] = 'abort';
            }
            $file["size"] = $file_size;
            $file["name"] = $uploadDirRelative.$file["name"];
            $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
        }
        return $file;
    }

    public function get() {
        $file_name = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ?
            basename(db_stripslashesbinary($_REQUEST['file'])) : null;
        if ($file_name) {
            $info = $this->get_file_object($file_name);
        } else {
            $info = $this->get_file_objects();
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo my_json_encode($info);
    }

    public function post() {
        $upload = uploadFiles($this->options['param_name']);
        $info = array();
        foreach ($upload as $index => $uploadedFile) {
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload($uploadedFile, $index);
        }
        /*} elseif ($upload) {
            // param_name is a single object identifier like "file",
            // $_FILES is a one-dimensional array:
            $info[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                $upload['tmp_name'],
                $upload['name'],
                $upload['size'],
                $upload['type'],
                $upload['error'],
                0
            ); 
        }*/
        header('Vary: Accept');
        $result = array();
        foreach ($info as $file)
        {
            if($file["error"] === false)
            {
                $sessionArray = array();
                $sessionArray["file"] = $file;
                $sessionArray["fromDB"] = false;
                $sessionArray["deleted"] = false;
                $_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp][$file["usrName"]] = $sessionArray;
            }
            $userFile = $this->buildUserFile($file);
            if(!$userFile["isImg"]){
                $userFile["isImg"] = true;
                $userFile["thumbnail_url"] = $userFile["url"]."&icon=1";
            }
            $result[] = $userFile; 
        }
        $json = my_json_encode($result);
        if (IsJSONAccepted()) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
        } else {
            header('Content-type: text/plain');
        }
        echo $json;
    }

    public function buildUserFile($file)
    {
        $userFile = array();
        $userFile["name"] = $file["usrName"];
        $userFile["size"] = $file["size"];
        $userFile["type"] = $file["type"];
        $userFile["isImg"] = CheckImageExtension($file["name"]) != false;
        if($file["error"])
            $userFile["error"] = $file["error"];
        $hasThumbnail = $file["thumbnail"] != "";
        $userFile["url"] = GetTableLink("mfhandler", "", "file=".rawurlencode($userFile["name"])."&table=".rawurlencode($this->table)
            ."&field=".rawurlencode($this->field)."&pageType=".rawurlencode($this->pageType)
            .($this->tkeys != "" ? $this->tkeys : "&fkey=".$this->formStamp));
        if($hasThumbnail)
            $userFile["thumbnail_url"] = $userFile["url"]."&thumbnail=1";
        else 
            $userFile["thumbnail_url"] = '';
        return $userFile;
    }

    public function delete() {
        $fileName = postvalue("fileName");
        $success = false;
        if(isset($_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp][$fileName]))
        {
            if(!$_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp][$fileName]["fromDB"])
            {
                $sessionFile = $_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp][$fileName]["file"];
                $file_path = $sessionFile["name"];
                if (is_file($file_path)) {
                    $success = unlink($file_path);
                }
                if ($success && $sessionFile["thumbnail"] != "") {
                    $file = $sessionFile["thumbnail"];
                    if (is_file($file)) {
                        unlink($file);
                    }
                }
                unset($_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp][$fileName]);
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION["mupload_".$this->formStamp][$fileName]["deleted"] = true;
                $success = true;
            }
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo my_json_encode($success);
    }

    // runnerfix
    public function tempnam_sfx($path, $prefix, $suffix ){ 
        do{ 
            $fileName = $prefix."_".generatePassword(8).'.'.$suffix;
            $file = $path.$fileName; 
            $fp = @fopen($file, 'x'); 
        }while(!$fp); 

        fclose($fp); 
        return $fileName; 
    } 
    function create_scaled_image($file_path, $uploadDir, $new_file_name, $options, &$file, $isThumbnail, $uploadDirRelative, $uploadedFile) {

        $img_size = runner_getimagesize($file_path, $uploadedFile);
        $img_width = $img_size[0];
        $img_height = $img_size[1];

        $new_file_path = $uploadDir.$new_file_name;

        if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
            unlink($new_file_path);
            return false;
        }


        $scale = min(
            $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
            $options['max_height'] / $img_height
        );
        if ($scale >= 1) {
            if ($file_path !== $new_file_path) {
                $result = copy($file_path, $new_file_path);
                if($result && $isThumbnail){
                    $file["thumbnail"] = $uploadDirRelative.$new_file_name;
                    $file["thumbnail_size"] = filesize($file_path);
                    $file["thumbnail_type"] = $file["type"];
                }
                return $result;
            }
            return false;
        }
        $new_width = $img_width * $scale;
        $new_height = $img_height * $scale;
        $success = imageCreateThumb($new_width, $new_height, $img_width, $img_height, $file_path, $options, $new_file_path, $uploadedFile);
        if($success){
            if($isThumbnail){
                $file["thumbnail"] = $uploadDirRelative.$new_file_name;
                $file["thumbnail_size"] = filesize($new_file_path);
                $file["thumbnail_type"] = $file["type"];
            }else{
                $file["name"] = $new_file_name;
                $file["size"] = filesize($new_file_path);
            }
        }
        return $success;
    }
    function pathinfo_local($path)
    {
        $ret = pathinfo($path);
        if(!isset($ret["filename"]))
        {
            $extlen = strlen($ret['extension']);
            if($extlen)
                ++$extlen;
            $ret["filename"] = substr($ret["basename"],0, strlen($ret["basename"]) - $extlen);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can add it in the `handle_file_upload` function just before the `$this->set_file_delete_url($file);` line. Something like: `chmod($file["name"], 0777)`. This should get you close...

Comment: Upvoting my comment would be helpful :)

Comment: how to vote comments? I am new to stackoverflow. sory

Comment: @fijas dude just give a proper answer instead of a comment. I dont think a comment gives you stackoverflow points.